# What is the best way to communicate between a jsp page and a Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm making a dynamic web project in Eclipse and cannot figure out how to send a request from the user (via a button click) to a servlet that will perform some operation (including a database lookup) and then populate a webpage with the formatted results. I have all database lookup functions created. What is the best way to do this? I only really need one String to be passed back to the servlet, which will be the "category" of books that i wish to return as an ArrayList. Some sources seem to indicate that a jsp page should not even be used for relaying information to a servlet so I am very confused.

Comment: AJAX is the general solution here.  If you're using a JavaScript framework in your JSP page (generally recommended), such as jQuery, it will likely [provide API's](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) that simplify sending AJAX requests and handling the response.

Comment: I don't get all the ajax advice, this looks like a plain old jsp submits a form to a servlet, servlet does work, forwards the request to another jsp which will render the result. That's as classic servlet & JSP logic as you can get. Recommended reading: http://pdf.coreservlets.com/

Comment: @Gimby - My assumption is that because the question asks about communicating _between_ a page and a `Servlet`, it's implying a desire for a solution that works without reloading the entire page each time a new message is sent to the server.  That assumption could be wrong, however.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Form Submit

   ```
   <form action="/myServlet" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="category" id="category"/>
       <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
   ```

   And then in your servlet code (doPost()):

   ```
   String category = request.getParameter("category");
   ```
2. Using ajax (jQuery ajax is much cleaner)

   ```
   $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "/myServlet",
       data: { category: $("#category").val()} //post category field
   }).done(function( msg ) {
       alert( msg ); //alert html returned from servlet 
   });
   ```
3. JQuery Ajax (get)

   ```
   $("btnSubmit").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $.get("/myServlet", function(data, status){
           alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
       }); 
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to be working and is very clear

Answer (score 1):

You can send your "category" parameter writting it in the URL :
Servlet/?category=scifi and use request.getParameter("category"); in the doGet method.